# Добавляются обратные слэши в теги wordpress

Tags: wordpress

расширил редактирование рубрик кастомным полем, код:

```
<code>
add_action('admin_init', 'category_custom_fields', 1);
function category_custom_fields()
{
    add_action('edit_category_form_fields', 'category_custom_fields_form');
    add_action('edited_category', 'category_custom_fields_save');
}
function category_custom_fields_form($tag)
{
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option("category_$t_id");
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra1"><?php _e('Описание 2'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php $var = $cat_meta['cat_desc'] ? $cat_meta['cat_desc'] : ''; ?>
            <?php wp_editor($var, "textarea", array('textarea_name' => 'Cat_meta[cat_desc]')); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
function category_custom_fields_save($term_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['Cat_meta'])) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option("category_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['Cat_meta']);
        foreach ($cat_keys as $key) {
            if (isset($_POST['Cat_meta'][$key])) {
                $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['Cat_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        update_option("category_$t_id", $cat_meta);
    }
}
</code>
```

Почему-то при сохранении данных в это текстовое поле, все теги и медиафайлы добавляют впереди слэш и конструкция вида:
    `[caption id="attachment_2359" align="aligncenter" width="1200"] Нажмите для увеличения[/caption]`
    Превращается в вот это:
    `[caption id=\"attachment_2359\" align=\"aligncenter\" width=\"1200\"] Нажмите для увеличения[/caption]`

С ссылками такая же беда, добавляются \ в код. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что данные в `$_POST` экранированы. Используйте `wp_unslash()`

```
$cat_meta[$key] = wp_unslash( $_POST['Cat_meta'][$key] );
```